# How to give credit about an image I display in my website?

Tags: website-design, copyright, licenses

I looked for an image for decorating the main page of my website. I found a great image in Wikipedia. The license allows me to use the image, but, I must give credit to the creators (which includes their name and a link to their Flickr page).

My question is: what is the best way to give credit about the image, such that the page design will not be harmed?

In case it matters: my page is very simple - it contains only the image (floated right), a heading, a small amount of text, and some links. But, my question is more general and probably applies to many different websites.

Comment: If it's already stated you must include their name and link, then are you asking a design orientated question? Maybe this is more suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @w3d Maybe you are right. Can you migrate it to there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may add a description in the alt text, and wrap the image in a link, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.creditedsite.com"><img src="http://www.creditedsite.com/img.jpg" alt="credits goes here"/></a>
```

Comment: Does this satisfy the copyright requirements?

Comment: If you are really worried you can add a footnote under the image with visible text. It doesn't have to big, just barely readable.

Comment: OK, that is what I finally did.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the best idea if the authors care about credits. But most people don't, really, regarding images. The internet is completely saturated with stolen images.

Comment: This isn't what alt text is for. Most people never see the content of the alt text - it is supposed to be an alternative to the image, not to provide information about it.

Comment: I believe you could be found liable for breach of copyright as you are not visibly crediting the originator of the image as required. The usual way to do that is by displaying a caption either superimposed on the image or just below it, perhaps slightly smaller than your body text.

Comment: @bdsl that's a valid point. I will leave this answer up so that people may read the comments and decide if they want to take the risk